# Requirement of IP address connected by ad-hoc

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

How can i get the IP address of my computer connected to ad-hoc network created by the same computer?
Even if there is no internet access.
Already tried all the network settings.

Comment: if you are already connected, then `ipconfig /all` from an elevated command prompt should do it.

Comment: Duplicate of [IP address of host of Wi-Fi ad-hoc network?](http://superuser.com/q/109177/52492)